# Pandas: European style date_range

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, date-range

I am trying to generate `date_range` in European style `dd/mm/yyyy`

```
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range(start = '1/09/2016', periods = 10, dayfirst = True)
```

The output is as follows:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-09', '2016-01-10', '2016-01-11', '2016-01-12',
           '2016-01-13', '2016-01-14', '2016-01-15', '2016-01-16',
           '2016-01-17', '2016-01-18'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

And I get the same output without `dayfirst` argument.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing, the displayed format will be your current environment's display format, I don't think `dayfirst` is a `kwarg`, if you want a different output format you'd need to do `rng.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')` but this will give you strings rather than datetimes

Comment: So there is no other way to generate dates in European format?

Comment: No because what you're creating is an array of `datetimes` the display format is a completely different thing which is for your convenience, the underlying type is understand when performing arithmetic operations, really the display format matters when you're printing or displaying in plots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use only [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html), but lost `DatetimeIndex` and get `list` of `strings`:

```
print (rng.strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
['09/01/2016' '10/01/2016' '11/01/2016' '12/01/2016' '13/01/2016'
 '14/01/2016' '15/01/2016' '16/01/2016' '17/01/2016' '18/01/2016']
```

EDIT by comment:

If need daily frequency, add parameter `freq` to [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.date_range.html) and convert [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) `date`:

```
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range(start = pd.to_datetime('1/09/2016',  dayfirst = True), 
                    periods = 10, freq = 'D')
print (rng)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-09-01', '2016-09-02', '2016-09-03', '2016-09-04',
               '2016-09-05', '2016-09-06', '2016-09-07', '2016-09-08',
               '2016-09-09', '2016-09-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D')
```

Comment: So there is no other way to generate dates in European format?

Comment: No, datetime is convert to same way (US style) and if need convert it, use this solution.

Comment: But this is incorrect. Because the start date I want is 1st September 2016 and frequency of 10 days. So the next date should be 2nd September 2016. Since the dates generated are wrong itself, the conversion as you suggested has no use.

Comment: Thanks for the edit but it still does not solve my issue. It reads 9th January 2016 and so on but I want 1st September 2016.